# Are there Pokémon that can only be hatched from eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokémon Go, [it is known which Pokémon can be hatched from each distance of eggs](http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/eggs.shtml), with the 10km eggs having a chance to hatch into some of the highest CP-potential Pokémon in the game.

I know that some of the Pokémon you get from hatching eggs can also be caught in the wild. Looking at the Pokémon in the 10km egg category, I've caught Eevee, Dratini, Scyther, and Pinsir in the wild. However, I've never encountered wild Snorlax, Magmar, Lapras, etc.

For the sake of Pokédex completion (and having a better strategy at hatching eggs), are there some Pokémon that can **only** be obtained via egg hatching? If so, is there a list of said Pokémon?

Please note, I am not referring to region-locked Pokemon, as is being asked [in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277666/can-the-off-regional-pok%C3%A9mon-hatch-from-eggs). I am simply asking if there are any Pokémon that are not obtainable in the wild **somewhere** in the world, where the only option to obtain one is to hatch an egg with it.

Comment: @BrianJ Yeah, it sounds like this supports pay's answer, that all catchable Pokemon can be encountered in the wild, but eggs give you another avenue to obtain some of the rarer ones. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There are wild Snorlax and Lapras in the wild: I've caught 2 wild Snorlaxes, and seen a Lapras in the sightings. As for Magmar, I've caught around 5, and I've caught a wild Electabuzz.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not really, no. The only Pokemon that would be considered to be 'only hatched from an egg' are the region-restricted Pokemon. But, even then, if you were to travel to one of those countries, you could of course catch those as well. The region-restricted Pokemon can be seen here: [What are the regional Pokemon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277603/what-are-the-regional-pokemon)

Edit: I feel it is important to add that this is still a pretty hotly debated fact. There was a survey done which claims to conclude that out of approximately 40,000 hatched eggs, none of the Pokemon were region-locked Pokemon. However, there are some people who claim (with evidence) that they *have* hatched region locked Pokemon. Some of these people even claim to have spoken to the person who created the aforementioned survey, only to have that person dismiss their claims as lies or 'hacking'.

So, right now, I am leaning towards that it IS possible to hatch region-locked Pokemon, however, there is yet to be 100% conclusive evidence either way. You can see some of the threads on Reddit where users have made claims for both sides.

Edit 2: Just to be clear, the answer to the actual question at hand here still appears to be **no**, the edit above is just some additional information, some of which may be a bit beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw a couple other questions about the regional ones and hatching region-locked mons, but I was really focusing on the other, non-region specific ones. If everything is available in the wild, I guess the eggs are just another method to get some that appear less frequently out in the world. :)

Comment: Is there anything in the way of evidence other than that one comment that you can in fact hatch region restricted pokemon from an egg outside the region? [This thread on TheSilphRoad Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wlntp/my_coworker_hatched_a_farfetchd_from_a_5km_egg/) at face value would offer that proof but as you can see in the comments most people believe you can not.

Comment: I've added quite a bit to the answer. After searching more about this, I am not sure it is definitively answerable as of right now.

Comment: @DasBeasto there is another question asking about the region-locked Pokemon potentially hatching from eggs, [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277666/can-the-off-regional-pok%C3%A9mon-hatch-from-eggs). However, for the scope of my question, I was more asking along the lines of "Are there any Pokemon that are not accessible in the wild **somewhere** in the world, where the only option is to hatch an egg?". The answer to that still seems to remain "No". I'll update my question to make this point clear.

Comment: @king14nyr Yes sorry did not mean to clutter your question as my comment is out of the scope of that, it is in scope of the answer, however, as a large part was based on that, but it has been cleared up now.

Comment: @DasBeasto No worries, it's a fair point. I just wanted to clarify the focus of my question, and not overlap the same discussion on hatching region-locked Pokémon that is going on in that other question. And, now that question appears in the 'linked' section of this one, so if people want to dig deeper into that debate, they can on that one. :)

Comment: Oh ya, sorry, the information in my edit may be a bit out of scope for the question.

Answer (score 4):

Only a few Pokémon can only be hatched: baby Pokémon. They originally come from Johto (second generation) and hatch from all stages of eggs. They have been added in a very recent update, and [can't be caught in the wild](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-12-15-pokemon-go-how-to-get-togepi-pichu-and-every-baby-pokemon). They evolve using 25 candy.

Names: Pichu, Togepi, Cleffa, Igglybuff, Magby, Elekid, and Smoochum.

Ditto, on the other hand, *cannot be hatched at all.*

Comment: Sinnoh? Gen 2 is Johto. Sinnoh is 4th gen. Also, you don't really have to refute an answer that's already at -2. The downvotes kind of indicate that a post is incorrect/not good quality.

Comment: It was at -3, but I upvoted it. It states some true facts, and points out the Machop. Also, Venomous, I will check the pokemon books. Loading.....

Comment: What true facts could there have possibly been? There were two sentences. 1. I have caught many Machop and 2. Aerodactyl is only available through eggs. The first is a tangentially related comment that doesn't answer the question and 2 is completely untrue.

Comment: Also, could you please not type gibberish in your edit comments? If you don't have anything substantial to say in it, leave it blank. It will be autofilled with more descriptive information than "fwfqe"

Comment: All baby Pokemon in Pokemon Go are available in Johto and Sinnoh. A few are in other regions, such as Unova.

Comment: Happiny is not a Johto baby, but it is in Sinnoh.

Comment: Yeah; they didn't add it anyway.

Comment: Please add why you think this is unhelpful here, please.

Comment: @Iguanodon_Bubbles7777777 - You make some incorrect claims: 1) You state *"[Baby Pokemon] originally come from Sinnoh"*, which is untrue, the first Baby Pokemon (Togepi for example) came from Johto. 2) You say 'Pokemon Go is set in Kanto', which is not true: PoGo started with Kanto **Pokemon** sure, but there is no in-game indication as to the 'region'. If anything the 'region' is actually the "real world", per se. Everything else in your answer is fairly OK: If you correct the above statements, your answer will be a lot better.

Comment: The *GAME ITSELF* gave a notification saying the baby pokemon came from Sinnoh.

Comment: @Iguanodon_Bubbles7777777 where did you see this? Sinnoh has never been mentioned in relation to Pokémon Go in anything I've ever seen and it simply wouldn't make sense to add Gen 4 before Gen 2.

Answer (score -3):

You actually can get certain Pokemon from only eggs, today I hatched a machop, looked up where to catch him because I haven't seen him in my region yet, and multiple sources said only found in 5 km egg

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  If possible, could you list your sources?

Comment: I've caught multiple Machop in the wild.

Answer (score -5):

I have caught many Machop in the wild. Currently, the only Pokémon that has been stated to only be available through hatching an egg is Aerodactyl.

Comment: do you have a source? everything I have ever read, including official resources, have said that all Pokemon can be caught in the wild, minus the 6 that are not in the game yet (Articuno, Zapdos, Moltres, Ditto, Mew, Mewtwo)

Comment: Aerodactyl is most certainly available in the wild.